# Jmeter pasue thread executoion then execute sampler then resume all the thread

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

Hi how can I implement the following scenerio in Jmeter.
1. Thread group starts 5 threads.
2. 5 threads starts there execution.
3. all the thread pause until sampler  is exteded(need to be executed only ones by any thread).
4. after execution of the sampler, all the threads resume their execution.

Updated the question and image.

Is there any way to pause all the threads until, samplerA is executed by any thread ( irrespective of the thread count this need to be executed only once) after execution of this sampler all the threads can continue execution.
[Click for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccjcZ.png)

Comment: you need request 1 to be only once per thread or per test?

Comment: sorry , updated the question. I want to pause all the the threads in the group until a sampler is executed then resume all the threads execution.
( Note : the sampler need to be executed once irrespective of the thread count.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize your test as follows:

- Sampler 1
- [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) condition: `${__groovy(ctx.getThreadNum() == 0,)}`

  - Request 1

    - [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) code: `props.put('continue', 'false')`
- [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) condition: `${__P(continue,)}`

  - [Test Action Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action): Target: `All Threads`, Duration: `100`
- Request 2

Demo (pay attention to timestamps)

[image: JMeter Thread Synchronization Demo]